# Мне надо указать статус сборки моего maven проекта

Tags: java, maven, travis

Сказали В README должен присутствовать статус сборки от Travis CI (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/) или Circle CI (https://circleci.com/docs/status-badges).
Писал maven проект в Intellij Idea .
Я не знаю как это вытащить, проект готов, на гит хаб залил, что дальше?Очень надо узнать и побыстрей.Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отображения изображения билд процесса с помощью travis CI необходимо привязать к своему гит репозиторию ServiceHook.

1. Зайдите в настройки своего гитхаб-репо
2. Выберите Webhooks & services
3. В разделе services добавьте Travis CI (при выборе предложат перейти на сайт Travis CI, где можно залогиниться с помощью гитхаб аккаунта)
4. На сайте Travis необходимо скопировать выданный токен(его можно найти если перейти на аккаунт) и вставить в поле на гитхабе
5. В ридми добавить строчку, с вашими параметрами `[![Build Status](your travis url for the repo here.png)](your travis url for the repo here)`,

   например
   `[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/AndreyChugunov/netty.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/AndreyChugunov/netty)`
6. После добавления хука должна появиться зеленая галка у хука.

После коммита в ридми появится картинка со статусом, и должен запуститься билд. О статусе билда можно будет посмотреть на сайте Travis CI, для билда могут понадобиться свои настройки и полагаю это уже зависит от проекта. Например, мой чистый репозиторий не побилдился. https://github.com/AndreyChugunov/netty

UPD. токен можно посмотреть на сайте тревиса после авторизации, вверху справа нажмите на свой профиль и выберите Account, откроется страница аккаунта где слева вверху будет картинка с токеном. Нажмите показать токен. Затем его нужно вставить в настройках хука, там чтобы привязать хук тревиса нужно ввести логин, токен и пароль от аккаунта тревиса(по факту это будут креды гитхаб аккаунта)

UPD2. там где смотрели токен, справа есть небольшая настройка. Нужно передвинуть флажок, чтобы билд запускался при пуше изменений в репозиторий. После пуша, будет запускаться билд и в ридми будет появляться результат билда. Так же на сайте тревиса можно посмотреть подробности выполнения билда.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.Только у меня я не понял 4 пункт,какой токкен и куда?

Comment: Все сделал,токен добавил на гитхабе,ссылки по добавлял , серая кнопка с надпись unknown

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою невнимательность, но там где я брал токен справа только описание настройки для (Flick the repository switch on) что я уже сделал.В General Settings у меня стоят все флажки.Может не там смотрю?

Comment: Оставьте только билд при пуше и пулреквесте

Comment: Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration.
Написало в окне travicCI когда я запустил через circleCI . Я весь вечер натыкаюсь на этот файл но как и куда его создать так и не понял,подскажите?И картинка поменялась на build и failed

Comment: Здесь нужно исходить из целей использования тревиса и это отдельная тема. Если нужно чтобы билд прошел абы как для этого нужно добавить простой тревис умл, посмотрите как сделано в моем репо

Comment: Я просто взял ваш тревис файл, и вытащил свой xml файл на ружу из папки проекта,все сработало. Это вообще правильно сделал я или это я заставил программу выдать то что я хочу?

Comment: Вообщем спасибо вам большое!!!Выручили очень сильно!

Comment: В travis.yml вы указываете что должен сделать тревис с вашим проектом. В данном случае он выполняет команду mvn clean verify. То ли это что вам нужно от тревиса или нет судить вам:)

Comment: А что за язык испольузется в ямл файле?